# github merge rebase branch without conflicts

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase, git-rebase

I have two sibling branches(from master branch) in which I am facing conflicts while merging  both branches with master branch.
I have to merge them with resolving conflicts(or merge conflict fix commit).

master commit 1. init
branch1 commits are 1. init(inherited of master) 2. commit1
branch2 commits are 1. init(inherited of master) 2. commit2

when I use `git merge branch1` while on master branch. it works fine but then after I am running `git merge branch2` where i get conflicts. I need help in using git rebase to merge `branch2` into master without adding further commits

Comment: You have to fix the conflict during the merge and then commit your merge, there will be only one merge commit. Why do you want to rebase ? By the way you will have the same conflict to fix

Comment: @Ôrel it's kind of challenge to solve so i need to do it without adding merge commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                   o---o---o  branch1   
                  /
 o---o---o---o---o---o---o  master
                  \
                   o---o---o---o---o  branch2
```

From master branch first merge branch1:

```
git merge branch1
```

```
                   o---o---o  branch1   
                  /         \
 o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o  master
                  \
                   o---o---o---o---o  branch2
```

Then rebase branch2 on master:

```
git rebase master branch2
```

You will have some conflict:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: branch2
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   fileXXX
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in fileXXX

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

Edit each conflict files to fix the conflict then

```
git add fileXXX
```

And

```
git rebase --continue
```

You have now branch2 rebase on master

```
                   o---o---o  branch1   
                  /         \
 o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o  master
                              \
                               o'--o'--o'--o'--o'  branch2
```

Now merge branch2 into master

```
git checkout master
git merge branch2
```

```
                   o---o---o  branch1   
                  /         \
 o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o'--o'--o'--o'--o'  master
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it's done!
I even don't know how to mention you in a comment. anyways thank you.